# Use DateTime::createFromFormat to get the + 1 day (Next Date)

Tags: php, datetime

How can I used the PHP **DateTime::createFromFormat** function to get the next date on the calendar.

**This is what I have been trying**

```
$sdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '04/05/2014');
$sdate = $sdate->format('Y-m-d');
echo strtotime($sdate);
```

**Above code returns result**

```
1399118400
```

Comment: what is the output you are looking for?

Comment: I' am looking for 05/05/2014

Comment: `echo strtotime('+1 day', $sdate);`

Comment: You can't use `createFromFormat()` to add one day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **[DateTime::modify](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)** method:

```
$sdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '04/05/2014');
echo $sdate->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');
```